# Phonegap input control crashes app on iphone7

Tags: html, ios, iphone, phonegap

I have created a simple hello world type Phonegap app with a textarea. The textarea is 14 rows by 40 columns. Here is the markup of the index.html page:

```
<body>
<div class="app">
    <textarea rows="14" cols="40">
        This is some generic test inside the textarea.
    </textarea>     
    <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
        <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
        <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    app.initialize();
</script>
</body>
```

When running on an iphone 7, doing a "downHold" in the whitespace of the textarea, the Phonegap app will crash. 100% of the time.

The input control does not have to be a textarea. I've experienced the same thing using a textbox.

This behaviour occurs on 3 iphone 7s I've tested.  It does not happen on Iphone 5, Iphone 5SE, Iphone 6, Iphone 6S or Ipad Mini.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 0):

Disabling "3D Touch" on the iphone 7 resolves this issue.